# How can I improve a JpaRepository slow method performance which has a very fast query(run at PL/SQL developer)?

Tags: oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I had this repo (sorry for portuguese words):

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Long> {

  @Query("select new package.someDTO(lan.dataLancamento, lan.prazoVinculado, lan.valor, his.tipo, his.descricao) "
      + "from EntityA lan, EntityB his, EntityC cc "
      + "where lan.conta = cc.idCc "
      + "and   lan.historico = his.idHistorico "
      + "and   lan.dataLancamento >= :presente "
      + "and   lan.dataLancamento <= :futuro "
      + "and   cc.agencia = :agencia "
      + "and   cc.numConta = :conta "
      + "order by lan.dataLancamento asc")
  public List<someDTO> findByAgenciaAndContaEntreDatas(@Param("agencia") Long agencia, @Param("conta") Long conta, @Param("presente") Date presente, @Param("futuro") Date futuro);
```

And this method works, but it takes like 5-6s to return a 3 element list. On PL/SQL Developer, the same query takes 0.015s:

```
select lan.data_lancamento,
       lan.prazo_vinculacao,
       lan.valor,
       his.tipo_lancamento,
       his.descricao
  from tableA lan, tableB his, tableC cc
 where lan.cc = cc.id_cc
   and lan.historico = his.id_historico
   and lan.data_lancamento >= '17/05/2012'
   and lan.data_lancamento <= '17/08/2012'
   and cc.agencia = 1
   and cc.num_conta = 201243
 order by lan.data_lancamento asc;
```

I'm using a local Oracle database. How could I improve this query to be faster? I thought I could use some `nativeQuery = true`, but this would stop from using `new package.someDTO` and since my query mixes data from 2 tables and uses a 3rd to verify some data. I can't create a new repository based on my DTO since it doesn't have any primary key and any unique attribute.

Comment: I rolled back your changes because it completely changes the question. 
Please create a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

These two queries look similar, but they are very different. Each difference might be the source of your performance problem.

1. the first one is a JPQL query, while the second is SQL. This means that

   a. It has to get converted into SQL which might look very different. Use the logging feature of your JPA implementation to double check which statement(s) actually does get executed.
   b. It doesn't just return some raw data but it instantiates Java objects. Depending on how your constructor looks like this might takes some considerable time.
2. the first one uses bind variables, while the second one uses literals. Oracle is smart enough to look at the actual where clause to estimate how many rows it filters out. But it can't do that if it only has bind variables. Therefore you might end up with completely different explain plans. => After you logged the statement that is actually executed get an explain plan for that statement (including the bind variables) and compare it to the one that performs well. This might give you a hint for additional indexes or similar that might help. Consider updating the question with the two explain plans if you need more help.
3. The java method returns all the results it gets from the database, while most SQL tools just get the first rows. This might as well be an important difference. Make sure you SQL toll show you all the rows before you stop the watch.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jens. After some time, I discovered why my method were taking so long and completely reformulated my question. If you can and want, could you please edit your answer?